# InetAddress keeps changing and i'm not getting the address i expected

Tags: java, networking

This is probably a **Network related** question, although i can't really find out what is going on.

```java
InetAddress giriAddress = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
String address = giriAddress.getHostAddress();
System.out.println(address);
//output
//74.125.24.147 as well as 216.58.210.228
```

**What i expected:**

- `8.8.8.8`

**What I got:**

- `74.125.24.147`
- `216.58.210.228`

**Note:**

And in fact by visiting both of these addresses I'm viewing google's homepage

**My Question:**

Why  `8.8.8.8` is not returned? Why these two addresses looping on each other?

Comment: Why are you expecting `8.8.8.8` ?  Also, chances are that google uses load-balancing across multiple servers.

Comment: I thought that `8.8.8.8` is the `IP` behind `www.google.com`

Comment: This is both 'unclear what you're asking' and 'off-topic'.

Comment: and why exactly is that? why is it off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

`8.8.8.8` is the IP address of Google's **DNS server**.

What you're getting are the **resolved IP** addresses of **webservers** hosting `www.google.com`

From [InetAddress#getByName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)):

```
Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name.
```

So it actually does the DNS resolving for you.

Comment: And why they keep on changing?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995808/dns-gethostentry-returns-multiple-ip-addresses